# How to minimise a function with parameter?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find a minimum of a function depending on a parameter, but I cannot get it to work. For example, I try to find the minima of $\sin(ax)$ where $a$ is a parameter. For example, trying the following doesn't return anything:

```
Minimize[Sin[a*x], x]
```

Trying something like

```
Assuming[a > 0, Minimize[Sin[a*x], x]]
```

Also doesn't work. What's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: You may try using `Reduce` like this: `Reduce[D[Sin[a x], x] == 0 && D[Sin[a x], {x, 2}] > 0, x]`. And the output reads: `C[1] \[Element] Integers && a \[Element] Reals && a != 0 &&  x == -((\[Pi] - 4 \[Pi] C[1])/(2 a))`. The idea is to solve for first and second derivatives to find min or max.

Comment: 1. Please have a look at FindMinimum[].
2. You may use D[] to find your solution applying the rules of calculus.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[a_, x_] = Sin[a*x];
```

To find all minimums

```
Assuming[Element[a, Reals],
 Solve[{D[f[a, x], x] == 0, D[f[a, x], {x, 2}] > 0}, x] // Simplify]

(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[(Pi*(-1 + 4*C[1] - 4*C[2]))/(2*a), 
           (Element[C[1] | C[2], Integers] || Element[C[1] | C[1] - C[2] | C[2], 
                Integers]) && C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0]}} *)
```

One example,

```
% /. {C[1] -> 2, C[2] -> 1}

{{x -> (3*Pi)/(2*a)}}
```

To find the minimum in a single specified cycle

```
Assuming[a > 0, 
 Solve[{D[f[a, x], x] == 0, D[f[a, x], {x, 2}] > 0, a > 0, 0 <= x < 2 Pi/a}, 
   x] // Simplify]

{{x -> (3*Pi)/(2*a)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *Mathematica* can analytically minimize a function with infinite amount of minima. How would you reasonable express the result? Anyways, `Minimize` works well for sufficiently simple functions:

```
Simplify[Minimize[(a*x)^2 + x, x], Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* {-(1/(4 a^2)), {x -> -(1/(2 a^2))}} *)
```

Note that you can give constraints on `x` but not on `a` within the body of `Minimize`. Therefore, `Simplify` is needed to obtain the desired result.

For most more sophisticated functions, numerical methods like `NMinimize` or (my favorite because of much better computational speed) `FindRoot` on the derivative. In the end, minimization is not trivial and requires some code that is somewhat optimized for your particular problem.